# Number of fields in a structure

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

I'm looking for the Number of fields of a table or structure.
Any suggestion please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For counting the components of a structure, better use RTTS as we don't want to access the database for result we already have in our environment.

```
DATA(lwa_struct) = VALUE kna1( ). " your structure e.g. kna1

DATA(lo_descr) = CAST cl_abap_structdescr( cl_abap_datadescr=>describe_by_data( lwa_struct ) ).

DATA(lw_all_fields) = LINES( lo_descr->components ). " => 184
```

Answer (score 2):

@lausek answered correctly. But for release 730 or lower, you'll need to adapt to something like this:

```
data ls_mara type mara.
data lo_structdescr type ref to cl_abap_structdescr.
data lv_count type i.

lo_structdescr ?= cl_abap_datadescr=>describe_by_data( ls_mara ).
lv_count = lines( lo_structdescr->components ).
write lv_count.
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution from my side.

```
select count(*) into @data(lv_count) from dd03l 
    where tabname = 'YOUR STRUCTURE NAME' and AS4LOCAL = 'A'.
```